# Getting row with highest value - if multiple rows take another condition

Tags: sql, sqlite, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table where I store "bids". I need to get the row with the highest amount per group (PlayerID). But if there are multiple rows due to a "bid" at the same moment I need to get the earliest one (BidDate).

My table and test date looks like this ([DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9vrkyrzkKL13eQm4HPTaxr/0)):

```
CREATE TABLE bid(
    BidID integer PRIMARY KEY,
    PlayerID integer,
    Amount integer,
    BidDate text,
    User integer
);
INSERT INTO bid VALUES(1,1,1500000,NULL,0);
INSERT INTO bid VALUES(2,2,5875000,0,0);
INSERT INTO bid VALUES(3,1,1500000,'1625513541.2904',505414867524517888);
INSERT INTO bid VALUES(4,1,1500000,'1625513541.33661',840702168863735889);
```

I tried different queries already. But If I get the max(amount) I am still left with the date.
You will see also Amounts of Null or 0 which I used for testing Min(NULLIF(BidDate)) which did not help.

The result I am expecting (wanted to achieve) would be in this case:

```
 BidID | PlayerID |  Amount  |    BidDate      |        User        |
 ------|----------|----------|-----------------|--------------------|
    3  |     1    |  1500000 | 1625513541.2904 | 505414867524517888 |
    2  |     2    |  5875000 |     0 or Empty  |         0          |
```

Any suggestion or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tricky part for your requirement is that in the column `BidDate` you have  `null`s or `0` (although you have defined the column as `text`).

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function with the proper `ORDER BY` clause that takes into account these irregularities:

```
SELECT BidID, PlayerID, Amount, BidDate, User
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
              PARTITION BY PlayerID 
              ORDER BY Amount DESC, COALESCE(BidDate, 0) = 0, BidDate
            ) rn
  FROM bid
)  
WHERE rn = 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=2c1c399febd8ab9a2940ec3dddf58deb).

Comment: Thanks. I have checked your demo and also informed me a bit more about the ROW_NUMBER function as I have never got to it or used it.
I will check the application of it but it looks very good :)

Comment: @Pierre ROW_NUMBER() is one of the window functions supported by SQLite since version 3.25.0 You can read more about it here: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-window-functions/sqlite-row_number/

Comment: @Pierre and if this answer solved your problem don't forget to accept it by clicking on the checkmark.

Comment: This was indeed the link I was referring to - good documentation so. Mostly worked with MySQL - SQLite is "new" to me. Will now try to apply your solution on my project as it works fine here.